# Google Script or Action Script to run a program on a Network Drive

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, vba

I am trying to run a Visual Studio Executable application say SAP Order Prerequisite Form.exe from a goggle sheet or some other mechanism.

Basically, no web browser will allow me to run an .exe file as its deemed a security risk. Trust me I have read enough about that now. Therefore I have created a Excel_Launcher.xlsm file that simply runs a macro and this works fine :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell("\\MyNetwork\SAP Order Prerequisite Form.exe", 1)
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I can't upload this file to a Google site so I though of creating the GoogleSheet with some action script to run this application and not having much luck really. 
I have also tried using the following script :

```
html>
  <body>
    <form name="form1">
      <input type=button onClick="test()" value="Open File">
      <br><br>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function test() {
        var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbooks.Open("\\MyNetworkDrive\Excel_Launcher.xlsm");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on an app that can run this file directly or via some google script would be great.

Comment: that script is not valid for a google sheet. not clear why you want to run it froma browser.

Answer (score 0):

Oh ...ok the reason is because we have an internal system called eTracker which allows a link onlyof the  the following types. It will not allow me to enter a link to a network drive to  run a .exe program directly.

Http:// 
Https://
Javascript.

So you see I thought that a Google sheet could launch my application for ne.